# Button's onClick is being called hundreds of times every second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have an `onClick` function for a button that is being called hundreds of times every second without any actual mouse interaction.

```
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      show: this.props.show,
      store: this.props.store,
      price: this.props.price,
      category: this.props.category,
      date: this.props.date,
      shown: "inline",
      id: this.props.id
    };
  }
  kill = () => {
    this.props.kill(this.state.id);
  };
  render() {
    const divStyle = {
      padding: "1em",
      border: "1px solid black"
    };
    function trashCanVisible() {}
    function trashCanAway() {}

    return (
      <div display={this.state.shown}>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
        <Button variant="light">
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <div style={divStyle}>
                <Col>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFilePdf} size="8x" />
                </Col>
              </div>
              <Col>
                <table>
                  <thead>{this.state.store}</thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{this.state.date}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <tfoot>${this.state.price}</tfoot>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td />
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <p>{this.state.category}</p>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{this.state.description}</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Button variant="light" onClick={this.kill()}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} size="1x" />
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This `onClick={this.kill()}` function is referencing the `kill()` function, which is a passed function that references the function `pop()` in the parent class:

```
pop(id) {
    console.log("pop" + id);
  }
```

I expect the `onClick=kill()` function on the Button at the bottom to run only when clicked. However, it runs all the time and gives a console output full of "pop1".

Comment: drop the parenthesis `<Button variant="light" onClick={this.kill}>`. You are actually invoking the callback for each render cycle this way. Instead you should give the callback handler a function reference to invoke when the user clicks

Comment: `<Button variant="light" onClick={() => this.kill()}>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
        <Button variant="light" onClick={this.kill()}>
```

with

```
                <Button variant="light" onClick={this.kill}>
```

You're calling the kill() method during initialization which is not what you want. You want to pass a reference to the function within the onClick Method, so the referenced function gets only called when onClick() triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to `onClick={() => this.kill()}` and you should be good to go

Comment: just as a fyi its better to give the function reference than an inline lambda (for performance purposes) :)